# Why can "WHERE col LIKE 'a%'" use an index, but not "WHERE col LIKE '%a%'"?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I just found this post:

[MySQL like query runs extremly slow for 5000 records table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938349/mysql-like-query-runs-extremly-slow-for-5000-records-table)

And I'm interested in understanding asaph's post where he says:

> I wouldn't expect select * from customer where code like '%a%' to be
>   fast since it couldn't possibly use an index. Every record has to be
>   checked. Consider select * from customer where code like 'a%' if
>   possible since that could feasibly use an index.

Can someone explain the difference between the two select statements?  I know one has only one wildcard and will only find things that start with "a".  but why can that one be indexed?

Comment: I believe the issue here is not whether a column can be indexed or not but rather whether the index will be actually **used** in a particular query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the [actual details](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) of MySQL's B-tree indexes are more complicated than this, for most purposes it's close enough to say that having an index on a column lets the MySQL engine perform `SELECT`s on your table as if it was *ordered* by that column.

If the `code` column has an index on it, and you're searching for records where `code LIKE 'a%'`, then all MySQL (or whatever other SQL package, as long as it's sufficiently clever) has to do is spit out all the records from the start of 'a' to to the start of 'b'. However, if you're searching for records where `code LIKE '%a%'`, then having the table already ordered by `code` won't help you, because whether a row matches the WHERE clause has no simple relationship to its position in the index. So for the second query, there's nothing the database can reasonably do except check every character of the `code` entry of every single row in the table (unless it already has the result cached).

This is fairly easy to understand intuitively, because you can imagine doing something reasonably analogous yourself, as a human. If you want to find all the words in the Oxford English Dictionary that begin with 'a', then you just go through all the pages from the start of 'a' to the start of 'b', and everything you see is a word starting with 'a'. If you want to find all the words in the dictionary with an 'a' in them anywhere, then the dictionary being ordered doesn't offer you much help. If you're sophisticated enough, you can plausibly exploit the ordering of the dictionary *a little* (such as by using your knowledge that all the words before the first 'b...' word in the dictionary contain an 'a'), but ultimately you're gonna have to look at almost every single word.

Answer (score 3):

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> Most MySQL indexes (`PRIMARY KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `INDEX`, and `FULLTEXT`) are stored in B-trees. A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the `=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`, or `BETWEEN` operators. The following `SELECT` statements do not use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE '%Patrick%';
> ```
>
> The index also can be used for `LIKE` comparisons if the argument to `LIKE` is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character. For example, the following `SELECT` statements use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Pat%_ck%';
> ```

Answer (score 2):

MySQL uses [BTREE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) indexes.

If you have a string comparison using LIKE with a *leading* wildcard, then it's faster for MySQL to do a table scan because the index cannot be used to narrow down the results.

If you have a string comparison using LIKE with a *trailing* wildcard, then it's faster to use the index because fewer records need to be scanned.